# Creating sketchpad: difference between .html() and .append()?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm "copying" [this sketchpad project](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/RebootJeff/myLearning/blob/master/odin.js.sketch_pad/index.html) that is meant to fill up a page with an X by X square grid. In order to do so, I had to create a div container (filled with X squares), and then continue adding X div containers with `.append()`.

When creating (say) a 16x16 square grid, the sketchpad shows up perfectly. However, when I try to create a 64x64, the first, few rows of the sketchpad only fill up partially.

Looking into the problem, I notice the JS file ([github](https://github.com/RebootJeff/myLearning/blob/master/odin.js.sketch_pad/script.js)), I know that this line of code helps, but I don't know why:

```
$('#grid_container').html("");
```

In other words, why does `.append()` suffice for a smaller sketch, but not for a bigger sketch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#grid_container').html("")` is not needed the first time because the div is already empty. But when you click another button, the intention is that it creates a whole new grid. So you want to empty the div first before adding elements (using `append()`) That's why `$('#grid_container').html("");` is used to clear the existing grid if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation :

[**.html()**](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2)
[**.append()**](http://api.jquery.com/append/#append-content-content)

Answer (score 0):

The `$('#grid_container').html("");` with will clear whatever it is inside `#gridcontainer`.

[Append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) will not clear anything, it just adds another element to the end of the container.